# Knockoutjs databind creates more than one element

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to learn knockoutjs. So I was reading a write from this url http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

I just try to run a code from the above url but when I click button more than one `Li` element is getting created, it should only create one.

### here is the html code

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: myItems, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn }">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
```

### JS code

```
ko.applyBindings({
        myItems: ko.observableArray([ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]),
        yellowFadeIn: function(element, index, data) {

            $(element).filter("li")
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200)
                      .animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
        },
        addItem: function() {this.myItems.push('New item'); }
    });
```

the above code was posted in knockout js tutorial page but it is not working as expected. I have also checked the jquery animate function is being called but not changing bg color. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: What does *Li element is getting created instead of one at a time* mean?

Comment: when button will be clicked then one Li element suppose to be created but i have checked that many li are created when button clicked. what is wrong in the code.

Comment: @Liam check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/jkrxv8e8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted needs jQuery to run this part:

```
$(element).filter("li").animate({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }, 200).animate({ backgroundColor: 'white' }, 800);
```

If you don't have jquery the yellowFadeIn function will fail and apparently knockout tries to re-apply previous attempts at every click.

see you fiddle edited:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkrxv8e8/2/

Note also that the jquery documentation for `animate` says that `background-color` property cannot be animated unless [jquery.color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used.

Here it is the fiddle with the relevant plugin added

http://jsfiddle.net/jkrxv8e8/3/

Comment: i have checked your jsfiddle link but saw jquery animate effect not working. first bgcolor should be yellow then while but nothing happening like.

Comment: jQuery documentation fo animate says that background color cannot be animate without the "jQuery.color" plugin http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: i got the area where is the problem. jquery UI related js file need to be added. i did it and worked. thanks